# Center align not working on website

Tags: css

I have a script that center aligns perfectly on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gf3bqd5j/) but not on the [website](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/). Please guide me how can I make it center align on the website. Thanks.

```
<div style="background-color: orange; width: 1423px; margin:0 auto;text-align:center;"><img class="wp-image-2531 alignleft" style="clear: none;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/meet-beneficiaries.png" alt="meet beneficiaries" width="220" height="218" /><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><img class="alignnone wp-image-2533" style="clear: none;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/meet-clients.png" alt="meet clients" width="219" height="217" /></span></div>
```

Comment: as you can see on your fiddle the problem must be somewhere else on your webseite! you really want us to go debug it?

Comment: It's hard to read this fiddle as it has an inline css. Also I don't think this image centers there, as I can see two circles being slightly shifted to the right. i might be getting this wrong though - what you mean center aligns?

Answer (score 0):

it's because your images are floating left:

try to remove that class 'alignleft' via the wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You have a few styles broken the behavior of the `img` and the `text-align:center` on the parent.

- Remove the `float` from the first image that it's caused by the class `alignleft`.

  ```
  .alignleft {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
  }
  ```
- And for the second `img` needs to change the `block` behavior to `inline` or `inline-block`:

  ```
  img {
    display: block;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need simple `margin:0 auto` to be added to your img with class `alignnone wp-image-2528 size-full`, as first step. then to paragraph holding images of companies (VISA etc.) add `text-align: center` rule.
Then you have markup mess where two circle images are placed. There is a div which contains both of your images, but one of them is wrapped id span. Remove span, and add `display:inline-block` to second image, as it's being displayed as block, so it wraps to another line. This should heal problems you experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin: 0 auto;` will center the div.

In your stylesheet img.alignnone class doesn't have any associated styles so you could add this property to this selector :

```
.img.alignnone{
       margin: 0 auto;
}
```